# How to setup the camera into front view?

Tags: camera

Currently I am learning Blender and I have still some problems with the camera setup. I do not really know how to set it to the front view. If I press F12 then I can only see the corner of the picture.

[image]

I tried with some hotkeys but it does not work. I am using version 2.77. It is comfortable for me.

Comment: Numpad buttons control the orthographic camera positions. 1 = front, 3 = side, 7 = top, 9 = invert whatever view you have (ie top becomes bottom). Set camera to view with  `ctrl + alt  + numpad0`

Comment: Just a tip: You should use latest release instead!